# jsPlumb multiple connections

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I'm trying to do a connect pairs jQuery quiz, I found jsPlumb, but I'm trying to connect each question to an answer.

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/xzf0ffcu/17/

```
    instance.makeSource("sourceWindow1", {
        filter:function(evt, el) {
            var t = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
            return t.tagName !== "A";
        },
        isSource:true
    });
```

Does anybody has an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a simple loop that seems to work to allow you to connect all the questions to an answer.  http://jsfiddle.net/xzf0ffcu/18/

My update was to basically add the below function...

```
for(QuestionCounter=1; QuestionCounter<=NumberOfQuestions; QuestionCounter++)
{
  ...
}
```

I also had to update your variable names for the questions so they worked dynamically...

```
var state = instance.toggleSourceEnabled("sourceWindow"+QuestionCounter);
```

Comment: thank you sir! how can i check whitch element has been connected?